# Оптимизировать запрос mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица со списком заказчиков. Там около 22 полей.

При выводе списка есть фильтры по ним... И один из фильтров поле поиска.
Вводим текст и ищем.

Сейчас я делаю это так :

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);

                                if($search !=""){$query_text="AND (`org_name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `sfera` LIKE '%$search%' OR `d_fio` LIKE '%$search%' 
                                OR `d_phone` LIKE '%$search%' OR `d_email` LIKE '%$search%' OR `d_birth` LIKE '%$search%'
                                OR `k_fio` LIKE '%$search%' OR `k_phone` LIKE '%$search%' OR `k_email` LIKE '%$search%' OR `k_dolzhnost` LIKE '%$search%' OR `k_birth` LIKE '%$search%' 
                                OR `inn` LIKE '%$search%' OR `kpp` LIKE '%$search%' OR `ogrn` LIKE '%$search%' OR `ur_adress` LIKE '%$search%' OR `rasch_schet` LIKE '%$search%' 
                                OR `bank_name` LIKE '%$search%' OR `bank_adress` LIKE '%$search%' OR `koresp_schet` LIKE '%$search%' OR `bik` LIKE '%$search%' OR `fax` LIKE '%$search%')";}
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id!='' $query_text");
```

Но сами наверно понимаете как это не правильно( Может можно как-то оптимизировать его?

Comment: `concat_ws(',', org_name, sfera, d_fio, d_phone, d_email, d_birth, k_fio, ....) like '%$search%'` -- вместо многоточий остальные поля. Если запятая встречается в шаблоне, поставить другой разделитель.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае разумней использовать полнотекстовой поиск тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE MATCH(org_name,sfera,d_fio,d_phone**все поля через запятую**) AGAINST ('$search')
```

инструкция тут: [Полнотекстовый поиск в MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html)

Comment: Это только если таблицы MyISAM. Таблицы InnoDB индексы FULLTEXT не поддерживают.

Comment: @KiTE для полнетекстового поиска куча условий помимо типа таблиц, поэтому и вставил ссылку.

Comment: По ссылке расписаны примеры использования MATCH и AGAINST.
А MATCH и AGAINST применимы только к FULLTEXT. В качестве альтернативы используют плагин [sphinx][1]

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: @KiTE и про то что поля должны иметь FULLTEXT индекс, тоже написано, как и про ограничения, но согласитесь оно того стоит, не конкатенировать же поля через запятую. а для оптимизации, полнотектовой поиск, по моему мнению лучший вариант и быстрей и удобней.

Comment: Я не говорю что хорошо, а что плохо; чем стоит пользоваться, а чем не стоит. Я говорю о том, что, если у человека таблицы в InnoDB, он примером из ответа воспользоваться не сможет.